# 2sum with duplicate values

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

The classic 2sum question is simple and well-known:

You have an unsorted array, and you are given a value S. Find all pairs of elements in the array that add up to value S.

And it's always been said that this can be solved with the use of HashTable in `O(N)` time & space complexity or `O(NlogN)` time and `O(1)` space complexity by first sorting it and then moving from left and right,

well these two solution are obviously correct BUT I guess not for the following array :

`{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}`

Is it possible to print ALL pairs which add up to 2 in this array in `O(N)` or `O(NlogN)` time complexity ?

Comment: It depends on whether or not you consider this to be all pairs: (1, 1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, **printing out all pairs (including duplicates) takes `O(N2)`**. The reason is because the output size is `O(N2)`, thus the running time cannot be less than that (since it takes some constant amount of time to print each element in the output, thus to simply print the output would take `CN2 = O(N2)` time).

If all the elements are the same, e.g. `{1,1,1,1,1}`, every possible pair would be in the output:

```
1. 1 1
2. 1   1
3. 1     1
4. 1       1
5.   1 1
6.   1   1
7.   1     1
8.     1 1
9.     1   1
10.      1 1
```

This is `N-1 + N-2 + ... + 2 + 1` (by taking each element with all elements to the right), which is
`N(N-1)/2 = O(N2)`, which is more than `O(N)` or `O(N log N)`.

However, you should be able to simply **count the pairs in expected `O(N)`** by:

- Creating a hash-map `map` mapping each element to the count of how often it appears.
- Looping through the hash-map and summing, for each element `x` up to `S/2` (if we go up to `S` we'll include the pair `x` and `S-x` twice, let `map[x] == 0` if `x` doesn't exist in the map):

  - `map[x]*map[S-x]` if `x != S-x` (which is the number of ways to pick `x` and `S-x`)
  - `map[x]*(map[x]-1)/2` if `x == S-x` (from `N(N-1)/2` above).

Of course you can also **print the distinct pairs in `O(N)`** by creating a hash-map similar to the above and looping through it, and only outputting `x` and `S-x` the value if `map[S-x]` exists.

Comment: printing should be possible too if you do not distinguish between items of the same value.

Comment: Yes it is. Though distinguishing between pairs with the same values is exactly what my answer is about.

Answer (score 1):

Displaying or storing the results is O(N<sup>2</sup>) only.The worst case as highlighted by you clearly has N<sup>2</sup> pairs and to write them onto the screen or storing them into a result array would clearly require at least that much time.In short, you are right!

Answer (score 0):

No

You can pre-compute them in *O(nlogn)* using sorting but to print them you may need more than *O(nlogn)*.In worst case It can be *O(N^2)*.
Let's modify the algorithm to find all duplicate pairs.

As an example:

```
a[ ]={ 2 , 4 , 3 , 2 , 9 , 3 , 3 } and sum =6
```

After sorting:

```
a[ ] = { 2 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 3 , 4 , 9 }
```

Suppose you found pair {2,4}, now you have to find count of 2 and 4 and multiply them to get no of duplicate pairs.Here 2 occurs 2 times and 1 occurs 1 times.Hence {2,1} will appear 2*1 = 2 times in output.Now consider special case when both numbers are same then count no of occurrence and sq them .Here { 3,3 } sum to 6. occurrence of 3 in array is 3.Hence { 3,3 } will appear 9 times in output.

In your array {1,1,1,1,1} only pair {1,1} will sum to 2 and count of 1 is 5.hence there are going to 5^2=25 pairs of {1,1} in output.